# solutions to $x^{x+y} = y^4, y^{x+y} = x$ in integers

Tags: number-theory

Three of the elements in the solution set of the simultaneous system $$ x^{x+y} = y^4, \qquad y^{x+y} = x $$ are ordered pairs of integers $(x, y)$. Find these ordered pairs.

Substitution leads to nothing (well infinity), and I have no idea on how to start this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In many contexts, $0^0$ is defined as $1$. (How many functions are there from the empty set to the empty set, for example). Is this one of those contexts?

Answer (score 0):

If $y \geq 0 \to x \geq 0$, if $y < 0, x+y \text{ is odd} \to x < 0 \to y^4 < 0 \text{ contradiction}\to x+y \text{ is even}\to x > 0\to x+y \geq 0 \text{ or else $y^4$ is not an interger}$. Thus there are two scenarios:

$1)$: $y \geq 0$: $x+y = \dfrac{4\ln y}{\ln x} = \dfrac{\ln x}{\ln y} \to \ln x = \pm 2\ln y\to x+y = \pm 2, x = \pm y^2$. Can you continue?

$2)$: $y < 0 \to y = - y', y' < 0$. Can you take it from here as well?

Comment: $\ln y$ is not real when $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Whether $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution depends on your definition of $0^0$, which is sometimes made to be $1$. I'll assume here you don't define it. Let $xy\neq 0$.

$$(y^{x+y})^{x+y}=y^4\iff y^{(x+y)^2-4}=1,$$

so either $y\in\{-1,1\}$, giving us $(x,y)=(1,1),(1,-1)$

or $$(x+y)^2-4=0\iff x+y=\pm 2$$ with $y\neq 0$.

- If $(x,y)=(a,2-a)$ with $a\neq 2$, then $(2-a)^2=a$, so $(x,y)=(4,-2),(1,1)$, and after checking they work.
- If $(x,y)=(a,-2-a)$ with $a\neq -2$, then $$(-2-a)^{-2} = a\iff a(-2-a)^2=1$$

mod $a$ gives $a\in\{-1,1\}$, so $(x,y)=(1,-1),(1,1)$.

Answer: $(x,y)=(1,-1),(1,1),(4,-2)$.

Comment: I believe $(x, y) = (4, -2)$ works as well, just playing with $(x + y)^2 - 4 = 0$. I realize the exponent rules are on shakier ground with negative exponents, but it at least provides some guessing material.

Comment: You can rule out $x+y=-2$ more quickly observing that the second equation would make $x$ a non-integer.